# How to preserve homemade chocolates?

Tags: storage-method, chocolate, food-preservation

I make my own homemade chocolates, fillings are also prepared by me.

The question is how to preserve the chocolates for a long period of time?

As in keeping it in a refrigerator is it the right way to make it stay for longer period of time? If I keep the molded chocolates outside of the refrigerator it often changes its shape; though keeping it in dry cool place, if its more than 80 pieces? If an order is been placed the quantity and quality is absolutely up to mark, but some times I lack in presentation because of the change in shape of some few pieces.

Comment: How long is "a long period of time"? Days? Weeks? Months?

Answer (score 3):

The refrigerator will prevent the melting of the chocolate, but will add more serious problems - moisture through condensation. This causes sugar bloom, where the water dissolves the sugar, which basically ruins the piece.

Usually this can be mitigated with airtight sealing and proper handling, but this works best for square chocolate bars. As it seems that you want to store more elaborate chocolate pieces, I would worry about this approach being successful.

As you do this semi-professional, my recommendation would be to get a wine cooler; they usually have an operating temperature up to 18°C/65°F. This is the ideal storage temperature for chocolate.